# JQuery Ajax calls not working in Phonegap after building it

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

When I am running my project using `phonegap serve` in node.js, AJAX works fine. But when I created an apk file to test if it works when distributed, it does not work. I already added my csp and whitelist and none still works fine.

this is my AJAX call:

```
$(".credits").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL+"check_user.php",
            data: "devID="+device.uuid,
            success: function(html){
                if (html == 'true') {
                    $(".loading_status").text("Account Registered");
                    $(".index_button").fadeIn("fast");
                } else {
                    $(".loading_status").text("Account Not Registered");
                    //this closes the app.
                    //navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
            },
            error: function(jq, status, message){
                alert("ERROR 100: CONNECTION ERROR!");
            }
        });

        //REQUESTING FOR AJAX FUNCTION
        /*$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, opt){
            //$(".index_button").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".credits").fadeIn("fast");
            $(".loading_status").text("Loading...");
        });*/
    });
```

I already added this in my config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Anyone? thanks in advance. :)

Comment: it looks like my only problem is i cannot send data. any help pls?

Comment: install the whitelist plugin

Comment: I tried to install it using GIT CMD and it says Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android."

Comment: Can you post  your CSP? Your serviceURL is on internet or local network? Do you use https on the url?

Comment: I am using local network. <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> I am using http.

Comment: So you ge the `alert("ERROR 100: CONNECTION ERROR!");`? change it to `alert(JSON.stringify(jq));` and tell us the message you get

Comment: you say that you are on a local network, are the device and the server on the same network? are you using the local IP of the server to communicate?

Comment: it says: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Yes. they are on the same network. Yes, i am using the local IP to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag to your app's html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*">
```

Comment: I am currently trying it now. And I just want to know what is the difference of using 'phonegap build android' and 'cordova build android --release'?

Comment: '--release' is for generating the signed apk for uploading it to the Play Store. Without adding '--release' you generate an unsigned apk just for testing purposes.

Comment: Oh. I see. Even after placing csp in my header, nothing works. Even if I just wanted to pop an alert box, nothing works. But other scripts work fine. Thank you for putting up with me tho. :)

Comment: Have you rebuilded your app after changing the config.xml file? (cordova build android)

Comment: Uhmm. I've been using phonegap build android all this time. Is there any difference?